# Transform multi-class problem to multi-label problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, machine-learning-model, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification

I found [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/56170/transform-multi-label-problem-to-multi-class-problem) question but I need an answer to the other direction.

Example:
Let's say we want to predict if a person with a certain profile wants to buy product A and/or B. So we have 2 binary classes A and B that don't exclude each other:

```
A     B
0     1
1     1
0     0
1     0
...
```

(We don't want to predict how likely it is for a person to buy B if the person has already bought A.)
Does it - in general or under certain conditions - make sense to transform this problem into a single-class multi-label problem with 4 labels (4=#combinations of A and B)?
What if the number of binary classes is larger than 2?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the contextual link between A and B.

If they are completely different categories with no or low correlation, there shouldn't be necessary to have a single class multi label.

But if A and B are somehow connected, overall if they can represent a scale together (i.e. AB = [0 0] = 0 =  "low impact" or AB = [1 1] = 3 = "high impact"), it could be meaningful to have a single class multi label. It all depends on the correlation and the business point of view.

If you can give more information about the purpose of A and B, I might be able to give more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question to give more information but as far as I can conclude from your answer, in my case it doesn't make sense to transform the problem to a multi-label problem.

Comment: Yes indeed. In addition to that, multilabel single class shall sooner or later be transformed in numeric values in order to be understood by algorithms (or I don't know another method). As A and B are independent, it doesn't make sense to have a ranged value, otherwise it would give the data a wrong meaning. Consequently, you should keep A and B as binary independent values.